# How to Use bitmap recycle in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, lazy-loading, out-of-memory

I am having an issue with bitmap recycle. I am displaying the bitmaps in a pulltorefreshlistview. I have about 30-50 Images to download alongwith some text from webservice function. I am using lazyloading of images and downloading Images and decoding them to 80x80 size. My Issue is that I am getting OutOfmemoryError. So I done some R and D and know that bitmaps were not GC'd immediately. So I want to do recycle() the bitmaps for reclaiming the memory. where to call recycle() on bitmaps. I am using famous [lazylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012). in this below code after setting bitmap, i tried to do bitmap.recycle(). I haven't got any error like other reported on stackoverflow but strange thing is listitems are shown blank. I wonder that if I recycle() bitmap why the textviews, in the same row are effected. As there are big number of images my app crashing very soon. I would also like to ask how to recycle all the images set in Listview at a time. please some one help me.

```
//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use this library: [Android HttpImageManager](http://code.google.com/p/android-http-image-manager/)

It's easy to use with lists and I've never got a OutOfMemoryException using it. It caches the bitmap in memory and also in filesystem (you can change that behavior).

Also I would recommend you to not resize bitmaps on phone, but do it remotely on server if you can (of course you might not have that option).